# Couch DB I require a map/view reverse engineer to get to my original json format

Tags: json, couchdb

I have a `data.json` file that works fine with my app which follows the syntax

```
{
    "name":"TESTER",
    "shortname":"TEST",
    "reknown":"TRIAL",
    "bio":"TESTER is testing"
  },
```

However I want to move to couchDB  for scalability
I have structured my CouchDB so I have Database with 100's of documents
In a document I create a Field pane called content
and insert/nest the json file data above

How can I get CouchDB map/view function to return the data in the same usable JSON format as the original json file   without keys id's etc.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use [list functions](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/couchapp/ddocs.html#show-functions) or [show functions](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/couchapp/ddocs.html#list-functions) to format the document in any way you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert this as an individual document if you need to.

```
{
    "name":"TESTER",
    "shortname":"TEST",
    "reknown":"TRIAL",
    "bio":"TESTER is testing"
}
```

To get what you need, I'd add an other property `type`:

```
{
    "type": "person",
    "name":"TESTER",
    "shortname":"TEST",
    "reknown":"TRIAL",
    "bio":"TESTER is testing"
}
```

Then you can have a map function like this:

```
function(doc) {
  if(doc.type === "person") {
    emit(doc._id, doc);
  }
}
```

You can emit the document itself if needed but it's not necessary.

Then you can query this view and it will return a list of all the persons. You could use a `show` function like Giovanni pointed out but it's not exactly necessary.

The returned json will contain more informations and you could just filter the document on the client side to get only what you need.

```
map(function (doc) {
  return doc.value;
}, requested_document.rows)
```

To prevent the index to get bigger, you can emit null when it's possible. And query the view with `include_docs=true`.